# Pending intent not getting invoked in Twilio android client

Tags: android, twilio, android-pendingintent

I am using the sample [android client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=stackdocsupdate) in Twilio for making voice calls.I am able to do outgoing calls from the android client.But cannot receive any incoming call. The call is getting routed correctly between my server and twilio,and is even shown in the call logs,but activity is not invoked. Can somebody help me.I think there is some problem with the pending intent.

//MonkeyPhone.java

```
    public void onInitialized() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Twilio SDK is ready");
    try {
                capabilityToken = HttpHelper.httpGet("http://my server/token?client=jenny");
                device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, this);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HelloMonkeyActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            device.setIncomingIntent(pendingIntent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Failed to obtain capability token: "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

//HelloMonkeyActivity.java

@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        Device device=intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        Connection connection= intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);
        Log.i("Hello monkey", "device and connection are:"+device+":"+connection);

        if(device!=null && connection!=null){
            intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);
            phone.handleIncomingConnections(device, connection);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem or I should help you?

Comment: I solved my problem @anshul Tyagi

Comment: Will you please help me? @akshay

Comment: @AnshulTyagi....my problem was that the device was getting created as null with the Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, this); method. The this parameter that is the applicationContext was null. Passing the current context to this method,solved the problem

Comment: Oh, we use it to make a call. I also faced this problem for 2 days but I got solution by documentation. Did you implement the code for incoming call?

Comment: Hi there ,i m having some issue in receiving incoming call on mobile,not on app(means pending intent is not working). could you tell me how to resolve this

Comment: @yogesh Incoming call means a normal call or the call through the Twilio app?

Comment: I am facing same problem can you please help me ?

Comment: My first call is connected well after that i put app in background after some time i resume app and then i didn't get incoming call. activity not launched what could be the case please help

Comment: @YogeshSeralia can you please help me ?

Comment: @akshay can you please help me ?

Comment: @KhizarHayat  pls give more detail over this ... some screenshot or video and best one is you source code can help me get situation better.

Comment: @YogeshSeralia please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410494/android-pending-intent-not-invoked-in-twilio-incoming-call

Comment: @KhizarHayat, Could you place the  code snippet where you are facing the problem,

Comment: @akshay Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410494/android-pending-intent-not-invoked-in-twilio-incoming-call