# Android pending intent not invoked in twilio incoming call

Tags: android, twilio, voip, android-pendingintent

I am making calling app using twilio sdk i have integrated all stuff and it is in wokring condition. But the problem is when my android app remains in the background for long time then app didn't receive incoming call request , pending intent not invoked by Twilio Here is the code:

```
   if (!Twilio.isInitialized()) {
            /*
         * Needed for setting/abandoning audio focus during call
         */
            Twilio.initialize(context, new Twilio.InitListener() {

                /*
                 * Now that the SDK is initialized we can register using a Capability Token.
                 * A Capability Token is a JSON Web Token (JWT) that specifies how an associated Device
                 * can interact with Twilio services.
                 */
                @Override
                public void onInitialized() {
                    isInitialized = true;
                    Twilio.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
                    /*
                     * Retrieve the Capability Token from your own web server
                     */
                    retrieveCapabilityToken();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    isInitialized = false;
                    Logging.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    notifyOnStopListening(null,-1,context.getString(R.string.error_message_not_connecting));
                }
            });

        } else { 
            retrieveCapabilityToken();
        }
  }

private void retrieveCapabilityToken() {
// in the success of api response 
    if (clientDevice == null) {
            clientDevice = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken,deviceListener);
        }
         if(clientDevice != null) {                
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReceiveCallActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            clientDevice.setIncomingIntent(pendingIntent);
            isIntentAdded = true;
            Logging.e(TAG,"in addPendingIntent intent added");
        }
}
```

Any suggestion , help would be appreciated.

Comment: on which Android version are you testing this code ?

Comment: I have tested on android 5.0 and 6.0 both , when app stays in background for long time then this issue happens otherwise its working fine.

Comment: Ok, Use Foreground Service (if your concern is to keep your service/app alive for maximum time), or alarm manager to start service periodically to keep you service alive if **killed by OS** (this is what whatsapp/skype/imo uses ).

But be sure for pros/cons. of both approach.

1st one is more resource intensive,
2nd one is less , only if your alarms are not so frequent (i.e. < 30 mins).

Comment: What should i do in service or alarm manager ?